# Django DATE_FORMAT weekday name

Tags: python, django

I want to format date object in Django. Specifically, I want to use `DATE_FORMAT` in `settings.py`. Using [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date), I set it as: `DATE_FORMAT = 'l, m F Y'`. Lowercase `l` means weekday name.

In the template I use `{{ value|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }}`, but it never renders the weekday name.
If I do the: `{{ value|date:"l, m F Y" }}`, I get the results expected.

Are there any limitations which built-in date filters are allowed in settings.py?

Thank you!

Comment: By disabling `L10N` the problems seems to be resolved, but I have the idea that there is a little bug here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: due to *localization (L10N)*, the language-defined format takes precedence over your defined format.

The reason this happens is likely because you enabled `L10N`, which means that you do not use the `DATE_FORMAT` specified in your `settings.py`. This is specified in [the documentation on **`DATE_FORMAT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format):

> Note that if **`USE_L10N` is set to `True`**, then the **locale-dictated format has higher precedence** and will be applied instead

So by setting `L10N = True` in your settings, it will, if such format is defined for the language, take that format, and not the one you specified.

Indeed, if we import the `django.conf.locale.en.formats`, we see:

```
>>> import django.conf.locale.en.formats
>>> django.conf.locale.en.formats.DATE_FORMAT
'N j, Y'
```

So due to `L10N`, it is rendered as `'N j, Y'`, and indeed, if we render the timestamp with that format, the two are identical:

```
>>> Template('{{ value|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }}').render(Context({'value': timezone.now()}))
'Sept. 7, 2019'
>>> Template('{{ value|date:"N j, Y" }}').render(Context({'value': timezone.now()}))
'Sept. 7, 2019'
```

You can set `USE_L10N` to `False`, and thus use a specified format.

```
# settings.py

# ...

USE_L10N = False

# ...
```

or specify the format manually. But usually `L10N` is used to format dates (and other elements) according to the preferred way to display this in the active language.